# Android, how to save an Array of dynamic linear layouts?

Tags: android, dynamic, view

I made a dynamic linear layout with views on them. But when I close the application these linear layouts are gone. How can I save them? Whether The saveInstance could help me and how?

Comment: You close the application means you finish the activity. finishing the activity will call onDestroy(). so next time you start the app onCreate() will get called creating alll new views.

Comment: elaborate more,on what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

> How can i save them?

You don't. You save the data necessary to build them again. Somewhere, you have Java code that builds those `Views` from some data. You need to save that data, so that when your app runs again, you can retrieve the data and run that Java code again. Whether you save the data in a database, `SharedPreferences`, some other form of file, or on some server somewhere, is up to you.